# TCL script to print a string carrying certain pattern

Tags: tcl

Please find the input list

```
clk_mbist BIST_SETUP ltest_to_mcp_bounding_en bistEn ltest_to_en BIST_EVEN_GROUPWRITEENABLE BIST_ODD_GROUPWRITEENABLE BIST_SELECT BIST_WRITEENABLE {BIST_COL_ADD[1]} {BIST_COL_ADD[0]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[7]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[6]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[5]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[4]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[3]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[2]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[1]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[0]} {BIST_BANK_ADD[0]} BIST_DATA_POLARITY_EN BIST_COLLAR_EN4 BIST_ASYNC_RESET BIST_TESTDATA_SELECT_TO_COLLAR BIST_ON_TO_COLLAR {BIST_WRITE_DATA[1]} {BIST_WRITE_DATA[0]} BIST_SHIFT_COLLAR BIST_COLLAR_SETUP BIST_CLEAR_DEFAULT BIST_CLEAR BIST_COLLAR_HOLD MBISTPG_RESET_REG_SETUP2
```

I need to create a list when the regular expression matches with "{" or "}" , in simple words I need to create a list having the elements carrying curly brackets

My output list should be

```
{BIST_COL_ADD[1]} {BIST_COL_ADD[0]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[7]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[6]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[5]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[4]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[3]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[2]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[1]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[0]} {BIST_BANK_ADD[0]} {BIST_WRITE_DATA[1]} {BIST_WRITE_DATA[0]}
```

The script which I am running is

```
set input [list clk_mbist BIST_SETUP ltest_to_mcp_bounding_en bistEn ltest_to_en BIST_EVEN_GROUPWRITEENABLE BIST_ODD_GROUPWRITEENABLE BIST_SELECT BIST_WRITEENABLE {BIST_COL_ADD[1]} {BIST_COL_ADD[0]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[7]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[6]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[5]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[4]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[3]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[2]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[1]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[0]} {BIST_BANK_ADD[0]} BIST_DATA_POLARITY_EN BIST_COLLAR_EN4 BIST_ASYNC_RESET BIST_TESTDATA_SELECT_TO_COLLAR BIST_ON_TO_COLLAR {BIST_WRITE_DATA[1]} {BIST_WRITE_DATA[0]} BIST_SHIFT_COLLAR BIST_COLLAR_SETUP BIST_CLEAR_DEFAULT BIST_CLEAR BIST_COLLAR_HOLD MBISTPG_RESET_REG_SETUP2]

regexp {\{.*\}} $input matched 
puts $matches
```

But this is printing some elements which are not carrying curly brackets

```
{BIST_COL_ADD[1]} {BIST_COL_ADD[0]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[7]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[6]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[5]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[4]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[3]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[2]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[1]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[0]} {BIST_BANK_ADD[0]} BIST_DATA_POLARITY_EN BIST_COLLAR_EN4 BIST_ASYNC_RESET BIST_TESTDATA_SELECT_TO_COLLAR BIST_ON_TO_COLLAR {BIST_WRITE_DATA[1]} {BIST_WRITE_DATA[0]}
```

Could you help me out ?

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong. `input` is a list, and none of the elements have braces. The braces you see are used for quoting. When you use a string function `regexp`, onto a list, obviously you cannot expect things to go well all the time, and you are forcing the quoting braces into actual braces. The expression you are using is greedy, meaning it will match anything between the *first* `{` and the *last* `}`.

Comment: Thanks Jerry , could you tell me how to resolve this . Do I need to change the regular expression ?

Comment: I told you that the braces you see are only used for quoting, i.e. they don't really exist. Knowing that, your question itself does not stand any more, so you should be the one saying what you are looking for exactly?

Comment: Ok then I require the elements in a list having only the "[" or "]" means the vector elements having numbers not the scalar ones     for example the below list                                                                                               {BIST_COL_ADD[1]} {BIST_COL_ADD[0]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[7]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[6]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[5]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[4]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[3]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[2]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[1]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[0]} {BIST_BANK_ADD[0]} {BIST_WRITE_DATA[1]} {BIST_WRITE_DATA[0]}

Answer (score 0):

> Ok then I require the elements in a list having only the "[" or "]" means the vector elements having numbers not the scalar ones for example the below list
>
> ```
> {BIST_COL_ADD[1]} {BIST_COL_ADD[0]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[7]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[6]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[5]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[4]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[3]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[2]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[1]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[0]} {BIST_BANK_ADD[0]} {BIST_WRITE_DATA[1]} {BIST_WRITE_DATA[0]}
> ```

On a list, you use a loop, or a command that works on a list, like `lsearch` for example. Since you are looking for `[` and `]` only, using glob style matching seems sufficient:

```
set input [list clk_mbist BIST_SETUP ltest_to_mcp_bounding_en bistEn ltest_to_en BIST_EVEN_GROUPWRITEENABLE BIST_ODD_GROUPWRITEENABLE BIST_SELECT BIST_WRITEENABLE {BIST_COL_ADD[1]} {BIST_COL_ADD[0]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[7]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[6]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[5]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[4]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[3]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[2]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[1]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[0]} {BIST_BANK_ADD[0]} BIST_DATA_POLARITY_EN BIST_COLLAR_EN4 BIST_ASYNC_RESET BIST_TESTDATA_SELECT_TO_COLLAR BIST_ON_TO_COLLAR {BIST_WRITE_DATA[1]} {BIST_WRITE_DATA[0]} BIST_SHIFT_COLLAR BIST_COLLAR_SETUP BIST_CLEAR_DEFAULT BIST_CLEAR BIST_COLLAR_HOLD MBISTPG_RESET_REG_SETUP2]
set result [lsearch -all -inline $input {*\[*\]*}]
# {BIST_COL_ADD[1]} {BIST_COL_ADD[0]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[7]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[6]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[5]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[4]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[3]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[2]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[1]} {BIST_ROW_ADD[0]} {BIST_BANK_ADD[0]} {BIST_WRITE_DATA[1]} {BIST_WRITE_DATA[0]}
```

<sub>`*` means any character in glob style matching.</sub>